# How to make swf file smaller?

Tags: iphone, flash, screen-capture, filesize

I'm trying to capture a video demo of my iPhone app so I can post it on Youtube.

I'm using Jing application (http://www.techsmith.com/jing/) for Mac, and was able to capture a video of the app. However, I looked at the resulting file size and it's 130MB!!! That's huge!
The video is 3:40 mins.

Any tips on how I can make the size of the file smaller, so that I can easily share it and post it on Youtube?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the dimensions smaller, don't have a keyframe as every single frame, change the quality from best to good, same for audio (best to good), change the format. Isn't it kind of strange that you're posting a SWF movie for an iPhone app? Haha, anyway, hope this works!